# Pandas, iterate over datafralme items and built new dataframe based on columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I've this issue, I don't know maybe I'm getting tired, 
I've this dataframe

```
tostack=pd.DataFrame([['tol', 0.001],
       ['solver', 'svd'],
       ['alpha', 0.001],
       ['tol', 0.01],
       ['solver', 'cholesky'],
       ['alpha', 0.001],
       ['tol', 1.0],
       ['solver', 'svd'],
       ['alpha', 1.0]], columns=["param_name",'param_set'])
```

I need to "pivot" this into this shape :

```
tol      solver      alpha
0.001      'svd'     0.01
0.01    'cholesky'   0.001
1          'svd'     1.0
```

I've tried to pivot but I get "nan" between rows with following code

```
pd.DataFrame(dic_loc, columns=["param_name",'param_set'])\
    .pivot( columns='param_name', values='param_set')
```

So, what I need it's to iterate over the items and append the values by row, for each 3 values.

Any ideas are welcome,

Comment: Refer to Q10 in the dup link.

Comment: you need pass aggfunc = first or ''.join, `tostack.pivot_table(index=tostack.groupby(tostack['param_name']).cumcount(),columns = 'param_name',values = 'param_set',aggfunc='first')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> new_df = tostack.groupby('param_name').agg(list)

>>> pd.DataFrame(new_df['param_set'].values.tolist(), columns=new_df.index)

param_name  alpha    solver  tol
0           0.001     0.001    1
1             svd  cholesky  svd
2           0.001      0.01    1
```